# Installing software using GPO and normal install

Tags: group-policy, installation

I'm building a Group Policy that will run on several terminal servers, but because installing the software through GPO needs a reboot before the software is installed and I need to have it working before a reboot is possible, I need to install the software manually.

If I install the software manually, will a GPO install cause problems, and is there anything I should keep in mind if it works?

The software is .net 4.7.2 and Zivver outlook plugin.

Comment: If you're installing the software manually why would you then use a GPO to install it?

Comment: I want to use GPO to install the software in case a server needs reinstall or another server is also added to the farm, that GPO takes care of software so it is all the same across the serverfarm. Its just that I need to install the server before I can reboot it.